# Math notations for categorical variables

Tags: logic, notation, education

I would like to formalise some operations I am doing, however it is unclear how I should deal with categorical variables.

Imagine a dataset with 15 distinct couples (`ID`). Each couple was observed 3 times (`time`).

Each partner has responded to two questions: `p` and `act`. `p` is a dummy vector {0, 1} while `act` is a categorical variable with 4 levels {a,b,c,d}. `_m` refers to partner male and `_w` to partner female.

```
      ID  time   p_m   p_w  act_m  act_w
 1     A     1     1     1      c      b
 2     A     2     1     1      b      c
 3     A     3     1     1      c      d
 4     B     1     1     1      b      b
 5     B     2     0     1      a      a
 6     B     3     1     1      b      b
 7     C     1     1     1      b      b
 8     C     2     1     1      c      c
 9     C     3     1     1      c      b
10     D     1     1     1      c      b
11     D     2     1     0      b      a
12     D     3     1     1      c      b
13     E     1     1     1      d      d
14     E     2     1     1      b      c
15     E     3     1     1      c      c
```

First, I am interested in formalising the matches on `p`. Because `p` is a dummy variable, it seems that I can simply write:

$joint_{jt} = (p_{jt}^{m} \times p_{jt}^{w})$

where $t$ denotes *time*, $p_{jt}^{m}$ denotes partner $m$ response at time $t$ belonging to couple number $j$ (and vice versa for partner $w$).

```
      ID  time   p_m   p_w  act_m  act_w joint_j
 1     A     1     1     1      c      b       1
 2     A     2     1     1      b      c       1
 3     A     3     1     1      c      d       1
 4     B     1     1     1      b      b       1
 5     B     2     0     1      a      a       0
 6     B     3     1     1      b      b       1
 7     C     1     1     1      b      b       1
 8     C     2     1     1      c      c       1
 9     C     3     1     1      c      b       1
10     D     1     1     1      c      b       1
11     D     2     1     0      b      a       0
12     D     3     1     1      c      b       1
13     E     1     1     1      d      d       1
14     E     2     1     1      b      c       1
15     E     3     1     1      c      c       1
```

However, it is unclear to me if I can use the $\times$ operator for categorical variables. Basically, what I am interested in is when $joint_{jt} = 1$ and $p_m == p_w$, then 1.

My question is, how do you formalise $p_m == p_w$, when $p$ is categorical? 
I have been told that I could not use *logical operators* in my papers (econ, sociology field), but that I should use the arithmetic operators. So, how do you express `TRUE/FALSE` mathematically?

Now I have

$jointact_{jt} = (joint_{jt} \times act_{jt}^{m} \times act_{jt}^{w})$

But this seems wrong to me.

Could I for instance do, first define a vector $act$ if $act_{jt}^{m} = act_{jt}^{j}$ is true

$$
act_{jt} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & act_{jt}^{m} = act_{jt}^{w}\\
0 & otherwise
\end{array}\right.
$$

and then combine $act_{jt}$, with $join_{jt}$, like

$jointact_{jt} = (joint_{jt} \times act_{jt})$

```
     ID  time   p_m   p_w  act_m  act_w join_j joinact_j
 1     A     1     1     1      c      b      1         0
 2     A     2     1     1      b      c      1         0
 3     A     3     1     1      c      d      1         0
 4     B     1     1     1      b      b      1         1
 5     B     2     0     1      a      a      0         0
 6     B     3     1     1      b      b      1         1
 7     C     1     1     1      b      b      1         1
 8     C     2     1     1      c      c      1         1
 9     C     3     1     1      c      b      1         0
10     D     1     1     1      c      b      1         0
11     D     2     1     0      b      a      0         0
12     D     3     1     1      c      b      1         0
13     E     1     1     1      d      d      1         1
14     E     2     1     1      b      c      1         0
15     E     3     1     1      c      c      1         1
```

Comment: "I have been told that I could not use logical operators in my papers (econ, sociology field), but that I should use the arithmetic operators." Who told you this and why are you listening to them? The things you are trying to do are naturally and correctly expressed with logical operators (specifically equality), and at best cumbersomely with arithmetic operators. In particular, arithmetic operators are not applicable to categorical variables at all.

Comment: What is $match_{j}$, and what do you mean by saying that you are interested in “when $match_j \rightarrow 1$ and $p_m==p_w$, then $1$”?

Comment: @SteveKass sorry I meant $joint_{j}$ not match!, so when join equals 1

Comment: @MeesdeVries. Ok thank you. So can I for instance mix the symbol $\sum$ with $p_{m}==p_{w}$, so the "sum of matches"?

Comment: @giacomo, why would you use a $\Sigma$? Why not define your `join` variable to equal 1 when $p_m = p_w$, and 0 otherwise? (Or when $p_m = p_w = 1$ -- it is not clear to me what that variable is trying to capture.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries, sorry I didn't explain myself properly. I will then use the `join` variable to construct a sum of matches by individuals. But its another question. Thanks.

Comment: I think @MeesdeVries has answered the question, but I also wanted to point out that while your introduction says you have $15$ “unique” (you probably mean “distinct”) couples, the data you show seems to have only $5$ distinct couples.

Comment: How would you express when $p_{m}=p_{w}$ is true and $join_{j} = 1$? So, these two conditions? (this is what I am trying to express with $jointact_{j} = (match_{jt} \times act_{jt}^{m} \times act_{jt}^{w})$

Comment: your definitions of joint/jointact have $t$ on the right hand side but not on the left hand side; doesn't $t$ follow from $j$?

Comment: @LinAlg you absolutely right, this is a mistake from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to use logical operators does not make sense. They are hard to avoid (your suggestion for $act_{jt}$ uses them to define cases) and their use makes the paper easier to read.

Fortunately, there is a notationally convenient alternative using orthogonality. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be an inner product and let $\{a,b,c,d\}$ be an [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis). Then, by definition, $\langle a, a \rangle = \langle b, b \rangle = \langle c, c \rangle = \langle d,d \rangle = 1$, while other inner products such as $\langle a,b  \rangle$ are $0$. Using $joint_j = p_j^m \cdot p_j^w$, you can write:
$$jointact_j = joint_j \langle act_j^m, act_j^w \rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

Given two integer-valued categorical variables $p_m$ and $p_w$, there are very many ways to express equality via a 1 or 0 using only "arithmetic" operations. E.g.

$1-{\dfrac {\left||p_m-p_w|+1\right|}2}+{\dfrac {\left||p_m-p_w|-1\right|} 2},$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-n|p_m-p_w|)$$

Try using one of these in your paper, then ask the editor to explain to you again why you're not allowed to use logical operators.